# If India would've made till here

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, phrases

Is the above sentence correct .about a sports championship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "not correct".  The fragment "If India would've made till here"--it's not a complete sentence--doesn't make much sense without a context or a follow-up.  Also, "till" is usually associated with time ("till now"), so "till here" is not a good phrasing.  "To here" or its equivalent would be better.  Likewise "could" makes better sense than "would".

On the assumption that "here" refers to a point in some playoff series, I suggest "If India had (or could have) made it to this point, then ...." [followed by the rest of the sentence].